# How to size WindowsFormsHost?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, windowsformshost

I am using a WindowsFormsHost to display 640x480 images.
The WindowsFormsHost works fine using Height="120" Width="160" and Grid.ColumnSpan="3" like this

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Margin="10 10 10 10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="WindowsFormsHostL" Height="120" Width="160"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

But when I try to double the size of the WindowsFormsHost like this

```
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="WindowsFormsHostL" Height="240" Width="320"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

the WindowsFormsHost is correct in the .NET xaml viewer but appears to get smaller, do a HorizontalAlignment="Left", and go square. This

```
Debug.WriteLine(
      "WindowsFormsHostL.ActualHeight " + WindowsFormsHostL.ActualHeight
    + " WindowsFormsHostL.ActualWidth " + WindowsFormsHostL.ActualWidth);
```

prints this

```
WindowsFormsHostL.ActualHeight 240 WindowsFormsHostL.ActualWidth 320
```

at so the runtime seems to think it is correct. I am doing clean builds. What am I miss-understanding? Why can't I simply increase the size of this WindowsFormsHost in the xaml?

Comment: If you declare a `WindowsFormsHost` to be a certain size, then it will generally be that size. Are you sure that the images are not being rendered too small in the `WinForms` control instead?

Comment: The images to be rendered are actually larger, 640x480. I have other code that can save the images as .bmps (on a button press) and in both cases (WindowsFormsHost Height/Width 120x160 and 240x320) they are saved as 640x480.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I asked... your question clearly states the size of the images. I was asking if whatever `WinForms` image control that you are loading the images into has *its* size dimension set.

Comment: @Sheridan Yes. The imagingControl default size is 150x150. Works perfectly now. If you copy your comment to an answer I'll accept it. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the Row and Column definitions for the Grid to be the size you want to show?

Row Definition:

```
<RowDefinition Height="240"/>
```

Column Definition:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="320"/>
```

Then set your Horizontal and Vertical alignments to 'Stretch' ?

Comment: This might work, but I've got other controls on subsequent rows in all of the 6 columns.